# Dependent and multiple dropdownlist in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create dependent dropdown list in Excel.

I have 4 columns. Company, Agegroup, Members and Area.

When I select company name1, I should get the set of details related to that company. I Used INDIRECR and SUBSTITUTE and it worked for 1st two column.

Without macro can I do this?

I have a Table1 - Companies

```
Company 1
Company 2
Company 3
```

For Every Company i have set of Data tables like

```
Age      Members          Area
```

I have taken two worksheets.

In Sheet1 I have all the data from all the companies and there itself I have created the Defined Names for Companies and for Other Columns.

In Sheet2, I am creating Dropdownlist.

In Cell A2 I have created my Companies list as =Companies in source area (as I have given the same name while defining the name ranges)

For 2nd and Dependent Dropdown(Age), I have used =INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ", "")) and it worked.

But for 3rd Dropdown which also should be changed when the Company name is changed, is not happening.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are trying to achieve, and post some examples of existing data and the formulae you've tried? It's not clear if you mean that you have a four-column table containing the information you want, and after selecting a company name in a drop-down list elsewhere, you want the information in this table to appear on a different sheet; or if you mean that you want to 'get all the set of details' from some other source and put it in this four-column table.

Comment: Can somebody look into it plzz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume there is one company: `Microsoft`. You currently have one named range (`Microsoft`) which contains a list of age groups; let's assume they are `Under 18`, `18 to 40` and `Over 40`. For each age group, there's a list of members.

You'll need to give each list of members a name derived from the company name and the age group; for example `MicrosoftUnder18` will have `Alice`, `Bob` and `Charlie`; `Microsoft18to40` will have `Dave`, `Edgar`, `Fran` and `MicrosoftOver40` will have `Gertrude` and `Hilary`.

Assuming drop-down 1 is in `A1`, drop-down 2 is in `A2` and drop-down 3 is in `A3`, you'll want the source of your drop-down in `A3` to be:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1&A2," ",""))
```

You'll need to repeat this for as many drop-downs as you require.

If your data are likely to change often, it may be easier to put your data into a regular format. If you are just trying to look through the lists, you can use a PivotTable without any data (just put the filter fields in the `Page` section and the people in the `Row` section); if you're doing anything more complex, a VBA routine can help you out. Maintaining lots of named ranges is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I tried it. But its not populating any results. I want to upload this xlsx file so that you can have a look. But am not getting how to upload here. Please suggest

Comment: Please suggest me how to upload it. as i tried but coudnt do it

Comment: You can't upload files to SO. Here's what I would try: (1) Instead of setting validation to `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1&A2," ",""))`, put that (without the `INDIRECT` wrapper) into the cell formula. This will allow you to see what is being used as the range. (2) In another cell, enter the formula `=OFFSET(x,0,0)`, where `x` is the exact string output in step `1`; in the examples above it might be `=COUNTA(Microsoft18to40,0,0)`. This gives the first cell in the range `Microsoft18to40`. If you get a `#NAME?` error, you need to check that the range is named exactly as expected.